# How to calculate size of table manually?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, types, sizing

I have **created table** as below.

[image]

With the reference of this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html). Calculating **size** of datatypes used for this table

[image]

**Aim:** for this calculation is to **predict the size of table** for **n-users** while creating or implementing the table.

**Queries:** 
Q.1)

```
Memory size of Unsigned int min: 0 max: 4294967295 = 4 bytes. 

By allocating int(11) means max: 4294967295 - 11 =4294967281(remaining size)?

or 

By allocating int(11) means  4 * 11 =44 bytes?
```

Q.2)

consider to create following datatypes used.

```
int(11)      =4 bytes
Var char(2)  =6 bytes(L+2 bytes(L is string value in byte) consider “amir” so L value is 4 byte)
Date         =3 bytes
-----------------------
Total        =13 bytes
-----------------------
```

Is above **calculation** is **correct**?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `calculate the size of the above query`?

Comment: Have to calculate the memory space occupies for an user 1. If we calculate it for 1 user means. we can calculate it for 100,1000 users.

Comment: Do you mean size of a record in details table?

Comment: @Rahul I think he means the `in memory` size of the result set being retrieved by MySQL for a particular query.

Comment: @Amirjohn alongside the actual data in the table there are indexes. One of them is the primary key (which is a unique index) and any other unique index or normal index ads up. Based on the execution plan of a particular query MySQL will be loading some indexes of a particular table into memory to help filter out data. Calculating the memory consumption affected by this in MySQL isn't going to be very deterministic.

Comment: @MihaiStancu & Rahul sir: Check out my updated questions,